Kotlin Multiplatform. iOS compilation fails. linkPodDebugFrameworkIos. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Symbol for kotlin/Experimental
I have got the problem after upgrade of xcode to 15+ from 14.3
My app worked fine. But last time i edited it in Oct 2023.
Then my mac had been upgraded to new macos and xcode also upgraded to v.15
And compilation of the iOS app stopped to work.
I have found recommendations to upgrade Gradle and Kotlin. I have done this. Gradle upgraded from 7.5 to 8.2 and Kotlin from 1.6.* to 1.9.24
Android app is compiled fine. But iOS has a problem.
There is the error. kmmsharedmodule is the name of my shared module
> Task :kmmsharedmodule:linkDebugFrameworkIos FAILED
e: Compilation failed: Symbol for kotlin/Experimental.<init>|-2598733490408306588[0] is unbound
* Source files: 
* Compiler version: 1.9.24
* Output kind: FRAMEWORK

e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Symbol for kotlin/Experimental.<init>|-2598733490408306588[0] is unbound
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.symbols.impl.IrBindablePublicSymbolBase.getOwner(IrPublicSymbolBase.kt:63)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.symbols.impl.IrConstructorPublicSymbolImpl.getOwner(IrPublicSymbolBase.kt:91)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.AdditionalIrUtilsKt.getAnnotationClass(AdditionalIrUtils.kt:137)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.AdditionalIrUtilsKt.hasAnnotation(AdditionalIrUtils.kt:159)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.mangle.ir.IrExportCheckerVisitor$CompatibleChecker.isExported(IrExportCheckerVisitor.kt:89)
Compilation failed: Symbol for kotlin/Experimental.<init>|-2598733490408306588[0] is unbound

* Source files: 
* Compiler version: 1.9.24
* Output kind: FRAMEWORK

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.mangle.ir.IrExportCheckerVisitor$CompatibleChecker.visitClass(IrExportCheckerVisitor.kt:124)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.serialization.mangle.ir.IrExportCheckerVisitor$CompatibleChecker.visitClass(IrExportCheckerVisitor.kt:87)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.accept(IrClass.kt:73)

Any idea what to do with this?
I can not find same error on the web. I have done usual basic things like "clean project", reset gradle cache etc.
